# How to send SMS using telephony in case of DUAL SIM in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sms, telephony

I am using telephony package to send SMS in Flutter, but I have two SIMS. And for one SIM I have balance and one has not. It is only sending SMS by default i.e using SIM 1 but I want is that the app should send SMS using SIM 2. But I am unable to send a message using the SIMs, it is sending by default

telephony package:

```
  telephony: ^0.1.4
```

Code:

```
final Telephony telephony = Telephony.instance;
  void sendSMS(String number) async {
    print(number);

    // Check if a device is capable of sending SMS
    bool canSendSms = await telephony.isSmsCapable;
    print(canSendSms);
    // Get sim state
    SimState simState = await telephony.simState;
    print(simState);
    
    telephony.sendSms(
        to: number, message: "Hey i am having Epilepsy Attack XD",);
  

    }
```

Please help me out how can i change which SIM to send a message on Flutter App

Comment: Did you find a solution?